# jQuery('data') returns html fragment in 'data' with missing data

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I make a jQuery get call to fetch a html fragment and do some processing based on that data

```
$.get($('.more a').attr('href'), function (data) {
        var $data = $(data);
        // other code using $data
    });
```

Here, 'data' is

```
<div class="topDiv"> Data goes here </div>
```

But $data shows as

```
<div class="topDiv"> </div>
```

Only the html tags are shown, while the text inside is not. IE has the same problem(?). However, Firefox parse it correctly.

When I alert($(data).html()) , Firefox shows the alert with proper html while chrome and IE show it with the missing text.

Since I am running my project on localhost I am unable to provide a URL for the html fragment.I am using an asp.net ashx handler to provide the html fragment. Basically, when we post a request to the handler, it returns a html fragment based on a query string parameter passed to it.

```
String content = "<html> <head> </head> <body>"+
"<div class="topDiv"> Data goes here </div>"+
"</body></html>";

context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
context.Response.Write(content);
```

**Resolved**

As mentioned in the answers, the 'html' fragment was not well formed. Firefox 3 seemed to accept it while Firefox 4, Chrome and IE did not.

Comment: What happens if you alert($(data).html())?

Comment: Can you tell us what the URL is so that we can verify that it leads the browser to a valid HTML document? And for reproduction?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's because `<div>text</div>` isn't really a valid html document in itself.  IIRC, divs are only supposed to contain block level elements.  Text should be inside p, a, etc.  So IE and Chrome are killing the text according to DOM standards, Firefox is letting it fly.  Tell jQuery the dataType of what you're getting is "text" instead, then insert the content into your div using html(textData) instead.

EG:

```
$.ajax($('.more a').attr('href'), {
    dataType: 'text'
}).done(text) {
    $('container selector').html(text);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How did this:

```
String content = "<html> <head> </head> <body>"+
"<div class="topDiv"> Data goes here </div>"+
"</body></html>";
```

ever compile with the unescaped quotes? If you fixed this, you should be rocking and rolling.